# MacBook Pro crash recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

I have problem with my MacBook Pro 2015 (i7, 16 GB RAM). It crashes when I open my session or enter in recovery mode. I did a SMC and NPRAM reset but no improvement.

Internet recovery by Apple doesn't work either, after downloading the recovery from Internet and loading the progress bar stops at 1/10.

Have you idea? RAM issue? I never opened it.

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination and can require some patience.

The first thing I would do is try running Apple Diagnostics to test your hardware.

**Run Apple Diagnostics**

Follow the steps below to run Apple Diagnostics:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Ensure you have no external hardware (e.g. keyboard, mouse, display, printer, portable hard drive, etc) connected
3. Restart your Mac
4. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
5. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
6. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
7. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 4 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Regardless, take a note of what happens and let me know how you went. Then we can proceed with further troubleshooting.

Comment: Nothing wrong in diagnostic mode.